# Searching in a dataframe based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing some string values:

```
df:

  column1

0 | a

1 | b

2 | c

3 | d
```

now I also have a `list = (b , c)`. It contains some of the values of the df.

I want to be able to find if for each of the values in the dataframe it can be found in the list.

```
0 | False

1 | True

2 | True

3 | False
```

So far I have used `x = df['column1'].isin(list)` but then it say False for all of the observations in the dataframe. I am assuming because it checks if all the values in the df are in the list. How can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks

Comment: Is possible check it not some traling whitesapces in data? How working `df['column1'].str.strip().isin(...` ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i implemented this but unfortunately I am still having the same issue

Comment: hmmm, if `isin` not working then is problem in data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['a','b','c','d']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=['Column 1'])
list1 =('a','b') #If you are using round brackets then that is not a list, its a tuple. 
df.isin(list1)
```

**Output:**

```
    Column 1
0   False
1   True
2   True
3   False
```

Note: If still not work then recheck all the values in the dataframe or a list, it might have unnecessary spaces something else.

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, with this simple data frame it works. How would i get it to reference column 1 if there was another column called column 2 containing (e, f, g, h)?

Comment: Solved: my list was the issue: had all elements saved as one string rather than each element as its own string